# Why select id using other index?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql8.0.27, here is my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `number` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_number` (`number`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

why "select id from test;" using idx_number:

```sql
explain SELECT id FROM `test`;
```

[image]

Comment: There's only one row. The optimizer probably decided that it doesn't matter what index to use.

Comment: That index will have number and id, and it looks like you don't have any significant number of rows, so there isn't any particular reason to care

Answer (score 0):

You can think that `select id from test` doesn't use any index, because you don't have a 'where' clause and just select all the items in the table. It's a 'traverse'(or 'scan') action on the table.

However, it indeed uses the `idx_number` index(aka: second index) to find all the `id` in the table, because `idx_number`:

1. **has all the primary id values**;
2. **is small** than the clustered index(aka: the table);

**So mysql choose to use `idx_number` index rather than the original table, traversing on the former is much faster than the latter**.

[`type`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_type) in `explain` output really indicates these difference:

- [`all`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_all): traverse on the original table;
- [`index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index): traverse on the secondary index, but it's also a `traverse`;
- [`range`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_range): this is really what we thought 'using a index';

As you can see in your question, `select id from test` uses `index` type(not `range`).

Answer (score 0):

> Indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes. In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for the row in the clustered index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

As a result, the secondary would be more efficient for getting all the primary keys since it will be smaller than clustered index. The clustered index's values would be the entire row (2 ints). The secondary's index's values would just be the primary key (1 int).

In your case, it might not make much difference. However, as the size of the row increases, this optimization provides even greater benefit as the size of the clustered index grows with the number of columns but the secondary index does not.